# Drop Down menu in Bootstrap us not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hi i just started working on twitter bootstrap.i am trying to create a drop down menu example.but its not shwing anything.can any one please tell me where i am wrong.my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

its not showing anything except heading Hello World.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the dropdown but you don't have the button that activates the dropdown.

Look here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
 Action
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <!-- dropdown menu links -->
 </ul>
</div>
```